# Why is this javascript class not running or why are the buttons in the class not working?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I would like to instantiate buttons when running the class.

```js
class MainGame {
  constructor() {
    //BUTTONS
    button1Player = document.getElementById("1player");
    button2Players = document.getElementById("2players");
    testing = document.getElementById("test");

    //set default value to false for players
    onePlayer = false;
    twoPlayers = false;

    button1Player.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("You have chosen single-player");
      onePlayer = true;
    });

    button2Players.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("You have chosen multiplayer");
      twoPlayers = true;
    });

    testing.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert(onePlayer);
    });
  }
  }
  
  game = new MainGame();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Project - Tobias game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Square game</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h2>Page Title</h2>

      <button id="1player">One Player</button>
      <button id="2players">Two Players</button>
      <button id="test">test</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button no alerts appears.
My procedural code is working. I am now trying to translate it to OOP. Why are the buttons not working as intended?

Comment: Good practice. Say exactly what the problem is. "Not working" tells us nothing.

Comment: Can you tell us what the buttons should do and what they currently do?  To understand "working as intended" requires knowledge of intentions.

Comment: Sorry. When I press the buttons nothing happens. I.e no alerts.

Comment: Your code is just creating tons of global variables. You are not creating an instance of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use the class you need to instantiate it with `new`. You are also creating a lot of global variables.

Below is the code cleaned up a bit. I kept it working the way you had it.

```js
class MainGame {

  onePlayer = false;
  twoPlayers = false;

  constructor() {
    this.addButtonEvents();
  }
  
  addButtonEvents () {
    //BUTTONS
    const button1Player = document.getElementById("1player");
    const button2Players = document.getElementById("2players");
    const testing = document.getElementById("test");

    button1Player.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("You have chosen single-player");
      this.onePlayer = true;
      this.twoPlayers = false;
    });

    button2Players.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("You have chosen multiplayer");
      this.onePlayer = false;
      this.twoPlayers = true;
    });

    testing.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert(this.onePlayer);
    });
  }
}

new MainGame();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Project - Tobias game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Square game</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>Page Title</h2>

    <button id="1player">One Player</button>
    <button id="2players">Two Players</button>
    <button id="test">test</button>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the instant of the class like `game = new MainGame()`